# Is it possible to Shift through opponents?

Tags: dnd-4e, shift

If a creature can shift more than one square, can it move through opponents?
(This matters with abilities like Tumble or creatures that can shift more than 1 square.)

Comment: This is unanswerable without editing. What game are you referring to?

Comment: Hello, Jermu, and welcome to the site!  I've edited your question to help make it clearer; if this isn't what you meant then feel free to edit further.  (And when you get a moment please read our [FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq).)  @TimLymington: Presumably D&D 4.  Tagged appropriately.

Comment: Usually in RPs a creature can move though 1 ally or attempt to move around opponents, but can't usually move through them (unless movement is magical e.g. a teleport spell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, unless another rule provides an exception that allows it.

A shift is just a type of move that doesn't provoke an opportunity attack. As such, you can't move through enemy squares unless the enemy is helpless or two size categories larger or smaller than you.

Comment: Check out the D&D quick-start guide http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/quickstartrules.pdf 3 simple rules

Comment: A rule that provides an exception that allows it (Epic Tier though): Flanking Maneuver - You can move diagonally even if a wall corner normally blocks such movement.
    You can move through enemies’ spaces. You provoke opportunity attacks for this movement as normal. You can’t end your move in an enemy’s space.